# Double sort portfolios

Tags: factor-models, asset-pricing

I am studiying the impact of two variables A and B on stocks returns. When I sort the stocks individually, I find that the long-short portfolios returns obtained for A and B exhibit high correlation. To some degree, this result is not surprising since variables A and B are somewhat related. At this point, however, I am not sure how to proceed. I would like some advice and maybe  references to papers or books you may know.

I was thinking doing a double sort to contruct 2x3 portfolios very much in the same way as Fama - French (1993), but using the variables A and B. However, I had not found any reference doing the same procedure in a context similar as mine.

Any advice will be aprecciated.

Regars.

Comment: What is your question? What’s the goal of your research?

Comment: Hi Kevin. I want to identify if characteristic B carries a risk premium independently of A.

Comment: I'd suggest conducting independent 5x5 portfolio sorts and Fama-MacBeth (1973) regressions.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the advice. However, I am not sure if that works, because my factors are highly correlated.